# how to initialize time() object in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, strptime

I am trying to initialize a time object like this:

```
t = datetime.time(0,0,0)
```

but I am getting this error:

```
descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

I have these things imported

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time
```

They seem a bit redundant so I am wondering if this is what is causing the problem

I am also using the strptime method and the combine method

```
    earliest = datetime.combine(earliest, t)
    value = datetime.strptime(value, format)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can create the object without any values:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.time()
datetime.time(0, 0)
```

You, however, imported the *class* datetime from the module, replacing the module itself:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.time
<method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>
```

and that has a *different* signature:

```
>>> datetime.time()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument
>>> datetime.time(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Either import the whole module, or import the contained classes, but don't mix and match. Stick to:

```
import datetime
import time
```

if you need both modules.

Comment: The three-parameter constructor is equally valid, just redundant. http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.time

Comment: @Martijn ok so what should I keep/change?

Comment: @Martijn I have tried only importing datetime and time but when I do this I now get this error: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime' refering to line : value = datetime.strptime(value, format)

Comment: @Santiago: that's a classmethod, call `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.

Answer (score 22):

The constructor for time is:

```
class datetime.time(hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]])
```

(from http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#time-objects)

This works for me:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: t = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)

In [3]: print t
00:00:00
```

Answer (score 9):

It's the fact that you're `import`ing a conflicting `datetime` from `datetime`. You probably meant `time`, except you're *also* `import`ing a conflicting `time`. So how about:

```
import datetime as dt
```

and

```
t = dt.time(0, 0, 0)
```